# PHP: give alert popup then redirect the page

Tags: php, header, echo

I am new to PHP.

When someone uploads a file size too big, I want to show them a warning popup and redirect them to a previous page (or vice versa).

```
if(file size is too big){    
   ob_start();   
   header("location:index.php");    
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your File Size is too big!');</script>";   
   ob_end_flush();   
   exit;    
}
```

This code above will just redirect me to index.php and doesn't show any warning popup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do something like

```
header("Location: index.php?Message=" . urlencode($Message));
```

Then on index.php...

```
if (isset($_GET['Message'])) {
    print $_GET['Message'];
}
```

In other words, `index.php` will always check if it's being passed a message in the url. If there is one, display it. Then, just pass the message in the redirect

if you really want to use a modal popup, generate the js...

```
if (isset($_GET['Message'])) {
    print '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $_GET['Message'] . '");</script>';
}
```

Note that this will break if you use quotes in the message unless you escape them

Comment: This is perfect thank you.
I was wondering if I have to worry about code injection since 
User can type whatever they want in the message.

Comment: Yes - See [this page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for a good guide

Comment: Can you give me an example of injection when using the code you gave me?

Comment: browse to the url `index.php?Message=%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%3Ealert('XSS%20Fail')%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E` (not encoded that's `index.php?Message=<script type="text/javascript">alert('XSS Fail');</script>`)

Comment: Having message in the address is troublesome, I will try to use $_SESSION

Comment: Your choice - but make sure you clear the message down so it's not re-displayed later.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("YOUR MESSAGE HERE");
location="REDIRECTION_PAGE.php";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `header("location:index.php");` sets the response code to `302` automatically.  The browser immediately redirects without looking at the contents of the page.

You need to either do the redirect itself in javascript after the alert is sent, or else have the page you're redirecting to do the alert.

Comment: Thanks, I thought ob_start(); ob_end_flush();  was going to fix the problem based on reading other post, but I was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The code goes like:

```
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 200000) //any file size, 200 kb in this case
{
 echo "<script type='javascript'>alert('File size larger than 200 KB')</script>";
}
header("Location: index.php");
```

The browser will be redirected to `index.php` page anyway, no matter the file is successfully uploaded or not. Its just that the popup will appear if the file is of larger size.

Comment: I do not think this will work.  The header must be output before any body content and a 302 redirect causes the browser to ignore body content anyways.