# php header redirect does not display contents?

Tags: php

I am trying to display the alert statement once insert is done in mysql database. However, it would insert and immediately redirect to the webpage. It would not display anything between that ? Is there a better way to display message then redirect ? I even tried sleep function.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO invite_email (email) VALUES ( '".trim($email)."') ");

echo "<script> alert(\"Congratulations! We will contact you soon when the app is launched \") </script>";

mysqli_close($con);

echo " Please wait you will now be redirected to www.xyz.com website";

sleep(5);
header("Location: http:/www.xyz.com");
exit;
```

Comment: No `echo` / output before sending headers possibly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you'll see why I [**marked it as a duplicate**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

you're missing '/' in the "Location:http://www.nomsite.com"

Comment: Won't make a difference.

Comment: It's not working, since output is sent before header() is called

Answer (score 1):

from [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) :

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703854/php-give-alert-popup-then-redirect-the-page) might be useful to you

Edit : As Joey Emery said, doing this entirely in js should work as well, and maybe a simpler solution than the link i posted

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to do this entirely in Javascript?

```
$('body').append('<p>Please wait you will be redirected.... (If you arent, click <a href="#">here</a></p>');

setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.website.com';
}, 5000);
```

(Yes this example uses jQuery, but only for appending the p tag).